# Counting values in a matrix conditionally

Tags: r

In R, I am wanting to count the number of different values occurring in a column of a matrix, but only if a certain value occurs in another column. To clarify, consider this matrix:

```
MAT <- matrix(nrow=5,ncol=2, c(1,0,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,0))
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
 > MAT
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    1
[4,]    1    2
[5,]    2    0
```

I would like to find the number of '1's occurring in column 2, but only if '0' occurs in column 1 in the same row. The only function I know which does something similar is `table`, but I don't think it can check another column; it can only exclude values in the data being checked. (Please correct me on this if I am wrong.) I have tried searching on the internet, but I only get hits to unrelated problems.

Can anyone help me find a function for this problem?

Comment: `apply(MAT, 1, function(x) x[1] == 0 & x[2] == 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
sum(MAT[,2]==1 & MAT[,1]==0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always subset the matrix with a condition like this:

```
MAT[ MAT[,1] == 0, ]
table( MAT[ MAT[,1] == 0, ] )
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the rows:

```
which(MAT[,1]==0 & MAT[,2]==1)
```

And the `length` of that is how many times that pattern occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` :

```
table(MAT[,2]==1 & MAT[,1]==0)
FALSE  TRUE 
    4     1
```